# Recover SEO after accidentally redirecting to another site

Tags: seo, google, domains, redirects, google-index

My website domain is `a.example`. I need to change/move to a new hosting. While doing this on my new host, I accidentally made an redirect error that make my URLs (.htaccess):
`a.example/article-1/` **redirect** to `b.example`.
(`b.example` is not related to me.)

I have fixed that error. The original URL `a.example/article-1/` is accessible on my website now normally, but it is not found on Google search, it's `b.example` instead when I type original URL in search box. I lost a lot of traffic and time with this. It has been a week.

How to fix and update the search results on Google?
Will Google update automatically index `a.example/article-1/` again? Is it just matter of time?  Is there anything else that is harmful to my site in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your a.example hasn't got identical content with b.example, here is no reason why it should not get indexed again in 1 - 2 weeks after you have removed the accidental redirect. It is just as if you have launched a new site. However, if you have some history of content on `a.example`, which has been shortly interrupted by the mis-redirect but now it is back again, you should recover well (not a rule, but rather my experience with me fooling around with redirects of microsites to main sites, in similar manner).

I am not sure what you meant by `/article-1/` URL. Did you redirect just this one page? Or did you do `a.example/*` -> `b.example/*`, and redirect everything? In the first case, your losses would be minimized. In second case, Google probably got a 404 on `b.example`, making the redirects invalid, which raises your chances to get indexed again soon. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @Marko36, thank you for your useful answer.
My situation is the first case. ' /article-1/' to 'b.com'.
Now the 'b.com', i have make it discourage from search engine. And i wait.

Comment: And so, other pages of your site remain indexed?

Comment: I still wait. I will update here when i see something new.  Do you think will Ms.Google re-index my `/article-1/` again?

Comment: If you have removed the redirect and it has inbound links, it wure will get indexed. Submitting a sitemap might help, especially if you have a large site.

Comment: Dear Marko.
I want to tell you that it has been get indexed again. It is more than 1 week.
Fell so good now. Thanks Bro for your useful support.